# Multithreaded Subset Sum with Haskell Parallel Strategies

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing

I am attempting to use `Parallel.Strategies` to parallelize my subset sum solver, and need a little help understanding what is happening.

### The Problem

Find the subset of numbers in `numbers :: [Int]` which sum to `100000000`.

Single-threaded solution:

```
import Data.List (find)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust, isJust)

numbers = [14920416,14602041,14088921,13371291,13216099,12153625,10896437
          ,10884343,10228468,10177453,9998564,9920883,9511265,8924305
          ,8452302,8103727,7519471,7043381,7028847,6418450,6222190,6215767
          ,6190960,5514135,4798322,3823984,3247980,837289] :: [Int]

subsequencesOfSize :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
subsequencesOfSize n xs = let l = length xs
                          in if n>l then [] else subsequencesBySize xs !! (l-n)
  where
    subsequencesBySize [] = [[[]]]
    subsequencesBySize (x:xs) = let next = subsequencesBySize xs
                                in zipWith (++) ([]:next) (map (map (x:)) next ++ [[]])

subsetSum :: [Int] -> Int -> Maybe [Int] 
subsetSum seq n = find ((==target) . sum) (subsequencesOfSize n seq)
  where target = 100000000

solve = map (subsetSum numbers) [n,n-1 .. 1]
  where n = (length numbers)

main = do
  print $ fromJust $ find isJust solve
```

### Parallel Strategy

Since I am calculating the subsets of size n separately already, I figured I could just use `parMap` to spawn calculation of each list of subsets of size n simultaneously. I replaced the `map` in the `solve` function like this:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

solve = parMap rpar (subsetSum numbers) [n,n-1 .. 1]
  where n = (length numbers)
```

#### Single Core

```
newproblem +RTS -p -N1 -RTS

    total time  =       35.05 secs   (35047 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 22,628,052,232 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                           MODULE  %time %alloc

subsetSum                             Main     86.6   24.5
subsequencesOfSize.subsequencesBySize Main     11.0   75.5
solve                                 Main      2.4    0.0
```

#### Two Cores

```
        newproblem +RTS -p -N2 -RTS

    total time  =       28.80 secs   (57590 ticks @ 1000 us, 2 processors)
    total alloc = 26,537,237,440 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                           MODULE  %time %alloc

subsetSum                             Main     70.2   21.4
subsequencesOfSize.subsequencesBySize Main     28.8   78.6
```

#### Four Cores

```
       newproblem +RTS -p -N4 -RTS

    total time  =       26.68 secs   (106727 ticks @ 1000 us, 4 processors)
    total alloc = 35,925,142,744 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                           MODULE  %time %alloc

subsetSum                             Main     68.2   22.4
subsequencesOfSize.subsequencesBySize Main     30.8   77.6
```

#### [threadscope comparisons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d12NC.png)

As you can see, the program does run quite a bit faster with 2 or 4 cores than on a single core. However, I do not believe the lists of subsets of size n are being handled by separate processors as I intended.

Looking at the threadscopes, it seems to me as if each "bump" in processor activity is the calculation on each subset of size n. I expected not a reduction in the runtime of each "bump", but "bumps" spawned in parallel across each processor. However, the former description is more accurate than the latter.

What is happening here? Where are the speedups coming from? Why is there so much garbage collection happening in between subset calculations?

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment whatsoever :D

Comment: Not sure if relevant: the `solve = ...` global non-function binding is possibly keeping a large result list from being garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion chi, I deleted the `solve` non-function and ran it again on 1,2, and 4 processors but didn't see any change in runtime or threadscope images. For reference, my new `main` function reads `main = do
  print $ fromJust $ find isJust $ parMap rpar (subsetSum numbers) [n,n-1 .. 1]
    where n = (length numbers)`